# how to set all inner values of 2d numpy array to the same size with default fill values

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have a NumPy array with many different sized sub-arrays. I would like all sub-arrays to be the same size. I do not want to delete any info so I would like to fill in the array with default values.

Convert this:

```
[array([ 1. , 15.5]) array([1.]) array([ 1. , 15.5]) array([1.])
 array([ 1. , 15.5]) array([1.]) array([ 1. , 15.5]) array([1.])
 array([1.]) array([1.]) array([ 1. , 15.5]) array([1.])
 array([ 1. , 15.5, 92. ]) array([1.]) array([ 1. , 15.5]) array([1.])
 array([ 1. , 15.5]) array([1.]) array([ 1. , 15.5]) array([1.])
 array([ 1. , 15.5]) array([1.]) array([1.]) array([1.])]
```

Into this:

```
[[1., 15.5, 0],   [1., 0, 0], [1., 15.5, 0],  [1., 0, 0],
 [1., 15.5, 0],   [1., 0, 0], [1., 15.5, 0],  [1., 0, 0],
 [1., 0, 0],      [1., 0, 0], [1., 15.5, 0],  [1., 0, 0],
 [1., 15.5, 92.], [1., 0, 0], [1., 15.5, 0],  [1., 0, 0],
 [1., 15.5, 0],   [1., 0, 0], [1., 15.5, 0],  [1., 0, 0],
 [1., 15.5, 0],   [1., 0, 0], [1., 0, 0],     [1., 0, 0]]
```

I used 0 as my default value in the above example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find the maximum size of arrays and use built in pad function to pad them all to the maximum size (you can even pass the value of your choice to fill in the padding in that function - default is 0):

```
l_m = max([i.size for i in a])
padded = np.stack([np.pad(i,(0,l_m-len(i)),'constant') for i in a])
```

output:

```
[[ 1.  15.5  0. ]
 [ 1.   0.   0. ]
 [ 1.  15.5  0. ]
 [ 1.   0.   0. ]
 [ 1.  15.5  0. ]
 [ 1.   0.   0. ]
 [ 1.  15.5  0. ]
 [ 1.   0.   0. ]
 [ 1.   0.   0. ]
 [ 1.   0.   0. ]
 [ 1.  15.5  0. ]
 [ 1.   0.   0. ]
 [ 1.  15.5 92. ]
 [ 1.   0.   0. ]
 [ 1.  15.5  0. ]
 [ 1.   0.   0. ]
 [ 1.  15.5  0. ]
 [ 1.   0.   0. ]
 [ 1.  15.5  0. ]
 [ 1.   0.   0. ]
 [ 1.  15.5  0. ]
 [ 1.   0.   0. ]
 [ 1.   0.   0. ]
 [ 1.   0.   0. ]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a fast method using `itertools.zip_longest`

```
np.array([*it.zip_longest(*map(np.ndarray.tolist,a),fillvalue=0)]).T
array([[ 1. , 15.5,  0. ],
       [ 1. ,  0. ,  0. ],
           < -- snip -- > 
       [ 1. ,  0. ,  0. ],
       [ 1. , 15.5, 92. ],
       [ 1. ,  0. ,  0. ],
           < -- snip -- > 
       [ 1. ,  0. ,  0. ],
       [ 1. ,  0. ,  0. ]])
```

We can sacrifice a bit of speed and simplify:

```
np.transpose([*it.zip_longest(*a,fillvalue=0)])
```

This still is way faster than the `np.pad` method:

```
timeit(lambda:np.array([*it.zip_longest(*map(np.ndarray.tolist,a),fillvalue=0)]).T,number=10000)
0.12874844600446522
>>> timeit(lambda:np.transpose([*it.zip_longest(*a,fillvalue=0)]),number=10000)
0.29307466209866107
>>> timeit(lambda:np.stack([np.pad(i,(0,l_m-len(i)),'constant') for i in a]),number=10000)
6.289798409212381
```

Variants

If the result must be C-contiguous:

```
np.array([*it.zip_longest(*map(np.ndarray.tolist,a),fillvalue=0)],order="F").T
```

If it must own its data:

```
np.array([*zip(*it.zip_longest(*a,fillvalue=0))])
```